# Why doesn't (day == 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday') check for weekdays?

Tags: python, if-statement

```
day = input("Enter a Day:")
is_vacation = input("Is this a vacation?")

if((day == 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thrusday', 'Friday') and is_vacation == 'No'):
    print('False')
elif((day == 'Saturday', 'Sunday') and is_vacation == 'Yes'):
    print('True')
```

If my input is:

```
day = Monday
is_vacation = Yes
```

Output:

```
True
```

I have used and the operator in first if block it should be false.

Comment: I'm guessing you came from something like JavaScript or Java: you don't need brackets around the `if` statement, Python doesn't need it.

Comment: wilusdaman answer is correct. I also suggest that you use one case so that way your input will never mismatch the array. So make everything you are comparing either lowercase or uppercase by using `.lower()` or `.upper()`

Comment: Only the second condition actually matters (e. g. to the right side of `and`). With the first one you are creating a tuple, either `(True, 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', ...)` or `(False, 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', ...)`, etc. - doesn't matter, a non-empty tuple always evaluates to `True` in conditional expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check for *membership* rather than *equality*:

```
if day in {'Monday', 'Tuesday', ... } and is_vacation  == 'No':
    ...
```

`day in {...}` will evaluate to `True` if `day` is equal to anything inside the set (that is, if the value of `day` is in the set).